# Make the SQL statement stop! Stopping supplemental log data never ends

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

We’re running a single-instance Oracle 11gR2 database for QA and development on Exadata hardware. I was asked to enable database-level minimal supplemental logging.  The database has just over 2T of data in it, stored on ASM. Archive log mode is enabled.

Recently, I was asked to enable identification key logging, so I connected as sysdba and ran `ALTER DATABASE DROP SUPPLEMENTAL LOG DATA`.  Six hours later, it’s still running.  Asking `SELECT SUPPLEMENTAL_LOG_DATA_MIN, SUPPLEMENTAL_LOG_DATA_PK, SUPPLEMENTAL_LOG_DATA_UI, SUPPLEMENTAL_LOG_DATA_FK, SUPPLEMENTAL_LOG_DATA_ALL FROM V$DATABASE` returns NO for all of the columns.  Does this mean there’s no supplemental logging enabled now and I can break out of my never-ending SQL command, or does it mean there’s no more supplemental log data being written but there’s still cleanup in progress?

I’ve considered opening an SR, but thought I’d check here as I would rather not let this run all weekend if it can be helped.

Of note is I am not an Oracle DBA - I’ve had the full time equivalent of about two months’ experience (maybe) so please go easy on me and explain things on a kindergarten level. I’ve read through as many Oracle Docs as I can, but there’s limits to what they can explain. Aside from resolving this issue, I’d like to take this as a learning opportunity.

Comment: You can see if your session is actually doing something by looking at it in v$session, it might not exist but your client process might have broken. But chances are, if Oracle reports what you want it to report then it’s probably done it - remember even DDL follows ACID principles, in this case atomic - it’s either all done or none of it. You probably won’t have any luck with an SR as your running an unsupported version.

Comment: I didn’t see anything relevant in v$session, and disk and CPU activity weren’t spiking, so I just let it run.  Sixteen hours later I got a success message and a SQLPlus prompt. Not sure if this is normal, but there were no errors or disasters so I’ll take it!